# SSRS to PowerBI - Can I deploy dashboards from on-prem db that users can access with PowerBI Free

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am currently trying to transition from SSRS reporting over to PowerBI.

I have a nice clean setup with SSRS with a Visual Studio and deploying reports to our users on prem.

Can I deploy dashboards from on-prem db that users can access with PowerBI Free?

I have PowerBI Premium for myself. When I try to deploy from on-prem source the users are getting a message that they need PowerBI Premium to access.

I need to do dashboards as well as serve up paginated reports to the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a [workspace with Premium capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-create-the-new-workspaces) in the Power BI Service. Because you have a Premium account, you should be able to do this. After you set up a Premium workspace, publish your reports, dashboards, and paginated reports to the specific workspace. After doing this, create an app in the workspace. Once you create the app, you can package all of the desired reports, etc. and share the app with your organization. The app *will not* require that end users have a Power BI Pro license. You can also share apps with the entire organization or limit them as you see fit, based off Active Directory groups or one-off individual accounts. Hope that helps! See the Microsoft documentation on apps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-apps).

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a pretty solid answer. I'm going to try this out and report back.

Comment: It didn't work for this when I tried this. Is Per Capacity required? I have the PowerBI Premium Per User license. Under Settings/Premium I only have two options for licensing type: Pro and Premium per user.